# reading directory remotely open in browser of window but not working in php script opendir() function

Tags: php, file

I am trying to read remote directory files from another shared system, able to open files in browser but getting error when reading using php script `opedir()` function.

Code:

```
$filesDir = "file://css-app-002-s/cs/files/";

var_dump(is_dir($filesDir));

if ($handle = opendir($filesDir)) {
    $dirList = array_diff(scandir($filesDir), array('..', '.'));
}

print_r($dirList);
```

error:

> Warning: opendir() [function.opendir]: remote host file access not supported, file://css-app-002-s/cs/files/

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688564/php-directory-list-from-remote-server

Comment: What kind of server is this on? Can you mount the remote resource to a local path and access that?

Comment: It is on Linux server, cant mount, only have to read from the network directory.