# What does this get_text function do?

Tags: php

[Panique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114320/panique) did a great job answering a question on this thread: [PHP directory list from remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688564/php-directory-list-from-remote-server)

But he created a function I don't understand at all and was hoping to get some sort of explanation. For example, what's with the random 8192 number?

```
function get_text($filename) {

    $fp_load = fopen("$filename", "rb");

    if ( $fp_load ) {

            while ( !feof($fp_load) ) {
                $content .= fgets($fp_load, 8192);
            }

            fclose($fp_load);

            return $content;

    }
}
```

Comment: do not put `$filename` in quotes on `fopen()` call. It makes no much sense.

Comment: I just used what Panique used (as mentioned), either way it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It loads the file which path is in `$filename` and returns it's content. 8192 is not random. it means read the file in chunks of **8kb**.

The `while` loop runs as long as the file wasn't entirely read. Each iteration adds the latest 8kb of the file to `$content` which is returned at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

It loads a file's data.

`For example, what's with the random 8192 number?`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

> Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline (which
>   is included in the return value), or an EOF (whichever comes first).
>   If no length is specified, it will keep reading from the stream until
>   it reaches the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

To break it down:

```
function get_text($filename) { //Defines the function, taking one argument - Filename, a string.

    $fp_load = fopen("$filename", "rb"); //Opens the file, with "read binary" mode.

    if ( $fp_load ) { // If it's loaded - fopen() returns false on failure

            while ( !feof($fp_load) ) { //Loop through, while feof() == false- feof() is returning true when finding a End-Of-File pointer
                $content .= fgets($fp_load, 8192); // appends the following 8192 bits (or newline, or EOF.)
            } //Ends the loop - obviously.

            fclose($fp_load); //Closes the stream, to the file.

            return $content; //returns the content of the file, as appended and created in the loop. 

    } // ends if
} //ends function
```

I hope this helps.

To elaborate on the 8192:

> Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline (which is included in the return value), or an EOF (whichever comes first). If no length is specified, it will keep reading from the stream until it reaches the end of the line.

from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php