# PHP fopen() Cannot Execute Opened Php Extension File

Tags: php, fopen

I open php file by fopen() and call it by fread() and fclose(), but it's not executed and it's just read as  when I open it by Inspect Element.

I tried it by htmlspecialchars() but it just printed as String.

I need some suggestions, please, in order to I can execute another php file from php. 
Thanks.

Comment: [`fopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) *opens a file descriptor, which functions as a stream to read or write the file* (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24008078/689579). If you want to execute the php file, you need to use [`include()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

Comment: Yes, I use include(), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Friend I think you can use file_get_contents().
IT can help you execute another php file from php.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: I had found the solution, I use import(), then I declare a function that I put the import() into it. 
After that I make a variable that calls the function.. 

My purpose is, I want to call n execute my "another" php file and put it in a variable.. 

Thanks.

Comment: @Garry14 yes include and require can help you do it.

Comment: Sorry, yes.. I mean include() :D

Answer (score 0):

I had found the solution. My purpose is, I want to call n execute my "another" php file and put it into a variable. 
I use inclde(), then I declare a function that I put the include() into it. 
After that I make a variable that calls the function..

I use this solution. 
[require/include into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948395/require-include-into-variable)

Thanks, btw ;)