# PHP: What's the difference between fopen('file.txt', 'r') and file('file.txt')?

Tags: php, file

What's the difference between `fopen('file.txt', 'r')` and `file('file.txt')`? They both appear to be the same...

Comment: to add to the confusion, there's also file_get_contents() and file_put_contents() to read or write a whole file

Comment: How so? All these functions have documentations explaining what they do. Just because the final result might be the same in some situations doesn't mean the functions are the same.

Comment: It was a good question. Too bad it's been asked before (and a lot).

Comment: [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) being the same? Where did you learn PHP from? Drop that tutorial and get your information from the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24008078/6203984) some info. Quote on `file()`, `file_get_contents()`, and `fopen()`:

> The first two, [`file`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24008078/6203984) and [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) are very
>   similar. They both read an entire file, but `file` reads the file into
>   an array, while `file_get_contents` reads it into a string. The array
>   returned by `file` will be separated by newline, but each element will
>   still have the terminating newline attached, so you will still need to
>   watch out for that.
>
> The [`fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) function does something entirely different—it opens a
>   file descriptor, which functions as a stream to read *or* write the
>   file. It is a much lower-level function, a simple wrapper around the C
>   `fopen` function, and simply calling `fopen` won't do anything but
>   open a stream.
>
> Once you've open a handle to the file, you can use other functions
>   like [`fread`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) and [`fwrite`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to manipulate the data the handle
>   refers to, and once you're done, you will need to close the stream by
>   using [`fclose`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php). These give you much finer control over the file
>   you are reading, and if you need raw binary data, you may need to use
>   them, but usually you can stick with the higher-level functions.
>
> So, to recap:
>
> - `file` — Reads entire file contents into an array of lines.
> - `file_get_contents` — Reads entire file contents into a string.
> - `fopen` — Opens a file handle that can be manipulated with other library functions, but does no reading or writing itself.

Credit goes to [Alexis King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465378/alexis-king).