# php warning on mkdir() when I'm trying to create a dir on a server address

Tags: php

I have a Warning on my php file at mkdir() function:

I want to make a folder on my server address so my code is like this:

```
<?php
    $link="\\10.44.96.4\\Arch\\down\\2018"
    mkdir($link, 0775, true);
?>
```

The real path is: `\\10.44.96.4\Arch\down\2018`
What I'm doing wrong?

**Later Edit**
The solution can be found here: https://www.codedwell.com/post/21/reading-file-list-from-a-mapped-windows-network-drive

Comment: What is the warning ?

Comment: `Warning: mkdir(): File exists in D:\apache\myfile.php on line 2`

Comment: Is that error message not ___SELF EXPLANATORY?___

Comment: The code is running on server, and the directory I want is on another server

Comment: At the very least you'll need to double-escape the two leading backslashes

Comment: I think this 2 backslashes are the problem `\\10.44....`

Comment: Thats what @iainn said try `\\\\10.44....`

Comment: Can someone put me straight here. Are you allowed to create folders on another server as easily as this? I find it kinda hard to believe that you can!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried, and it says: Invalid argument...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP directory list from remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688564/php-directory-list-from-remote-server)

Comment: @AmmoPT I'm not trying to access via ftp that server...It is a server where I put all my stuff when I'm working...

Comment: I am not sure that you can create folder in remote server,
but if you are running this script on the same server than it is better to try relative pats

Comment: @BOB, What you are trying to do is unheard of for almost everyone commenting here. If you are trying to create a folder on a remote server, you can use the `ftp_mkdir` function, which was created specifically for this purpose. https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_ftp_mkdir.asp

Comment: The answer is to map the server location to a drive letter and after that I can create directories. Unfortunately I need administrator privileges for doing that. You can view the php script right here: `https://www.codedwell.com/post/21/reading-file-list-from-a-mapped-windows-network-drive`

Comment: It would be nice if you would post a complete answer to your question and add the information that you are working with Windows and Windows/SAMBA shares. 